# Random SpriteKit texture switch statement not working correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm currently working in SpriteKit in Objective C, and I'm trying to set  a number of random textures in a switch statement to 9 different SKSpriteNodes. Currently, this section of my code looks like this:

```
int randomCard = arc4random_uniform(13);

switch (randomCard)
{
    case 0:
        staveCard = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Card_C.png"];
        break;

    case 1:
        staveCard = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Card_D.png"];           
        break;

    case 2:
        staveCard = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Card_E.png"];
        break;

    case 3:
        staveCard = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Card_F.png"];
        break;

    case 4:
        staveCard = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Card_G.png"];
        break;

    case 5:
        staveCard = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Card_A.png"];
        break;

    case 6:
        staveCard = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Card_B.png"];
        break;

    case 7:
        staveCard = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Card_C2.png"];
        break;

    case 8:
        staveCard = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Card_D2.png"];
        break;

    case 9:
        staveCard = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Card_E2.png"];                
        break;

    case 10:
        staveCard = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Card_F2.png"];
        break;

    case 11:
        staveCard = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Card_G2.png"];
        break;

    case 12:
        staveCard = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Card_A2.png"];
        break;
}

faceDownStaveCard1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:staveCard];
faceDownStaveCard2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:staveCard];
faceDownStaveCard3 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:staveCard];
faceDownStaveCard4 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:staveCard];
faceDownStaveCard5 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:staveCard];
faceDownStaveCard6 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:staveCard];
faceDownStaveCard7 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:staveCard];
faceDownStaveCard8 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:staveCard];
faceDownStaveCard9 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:staveCard];
```

When I run this on the simulator, all of the sprite nodes display the same random texture. However, I want the textures to be random for each sprite node, picking a different node each time.

Something like:

- pick random texture from switch statement
- add to first sprite node
- pick random texture from switch statement
- add to second sprite node
- etc.

Is anyone able to help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program's flow now is:

- Create random number
- Pick 1 texture
- Set that texture to every node

It should loop the first 2 steps the same amount of times as nodes present. Try something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i<9; i++) {
    int randomCard = arc4random_uniform(13);
    switch (randomCard)
    {
        case 0:
            staveCard = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Card_C.png"];
            break;

        case 1:
            staveCard = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Card_D.png"];           
            break;

        case 2:
            staveCard = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Card_E.png"];
            break;

        case 3:
            staveCard = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Card_F.png"];
            break;

        case 4:
            staveCard = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Card_G.png"];
            break;

        case 5:
            staveCard = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Card_A.png"];
            break;

        case 6:
            staveCard = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Card_B.png"];
            break;

        case 7:
            staveCard = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Card_C2.png"];
            break;

        case 8:
            staveCard = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Card_D2.png"];
            break;

        case 9:
            staveCard = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Card_E2.png"];                
            break;

        case 10:
            staveCard = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Card_F2.png"];
            break;

        case 11:
            staveCard = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Card_G2.png"];
            break;

        case 12:
            staveCard = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Card_A2.png"];
            break;
    }

    switch (i)
    {
        case 0:
            faceDownStaveCard1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:staveCard];
            break;

        case 1:
            faceDownStaveCard2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:staveCard];        
            break;

        case 2:
            faceDownStaveCard3 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:staveCard];
            break;

        case 3:
            faceDownStaveCard4 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:staveCard];
            break;

        case 4:
            faceDownStaveCard5 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:staveCard]; 
            break;

        case 5:
            faceDownStaveCard6 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:staveCard];
            break;

        case 6:
            faceDownStaveCard7 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:staveCard];
            break;

        case 7:
            faceDownStaveCard8 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:staveCard];
            break;

        case 8:
            faceDownStaveCard9 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:staveCard];
            break;
    }

}
```

This is just an idea of how the flow should be, please optimize the code. Good luck!

Comment: This totally worked for me, thank you so much! I'll remember this in future!

Comment: Haha, don't worry, anyway, try to re-write this code in a better way

Comment: I would also suggest using arrays instead of switch cases.